# this.form.name not working in chrome

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, label, this

Please help me, this.form.name and this.form not giving me current form name on label tag in chrome. Although it is working fine in mozilla and IE.

On input tag `this.form.name` and `this.form` is working.

```html
<li>
    <input type="text" id="listCount" class="field" name="listCount" value="${rowsPerPage }" onblur="javascript:numberValidation(this.form.name,this.value,this.name);" onkeypress="javascript:validateEnterKeyOnRowCountField(event,this.form,this);">    
    <label style="cursor:pointer;" onclick="javascript:getList(this.form,20,1000);">Per Page</label> 
</li>
<li>
    <label style="cursor:pointer;"  onclick="javascript:getListWithoutCondition(this.form.name);">
    <i class="ico ico-large-zoom"></i>
    View All
    </label>  
</li>
```

Please help.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: this refers to the label

Comment: I tried to replace label with span but still the same issue. Any other solution please.

Comment: use jquery to target the closest form

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add these two Javascript functions

```js
function getFormNameValue(elem) {
   var formName = j$(elem).closest('form').attr('name');
   return formName;
}
function getFormObject(elem) {   
   return j$(elem).closest('form').get(0);
}
```

```html
<li>
  <input type="text" id="listCount" class="field" name="listCount" value="${rowsPerPage }" onblur="javascript:numberValidation(this.form.name,this.value,this.name);" onkeypress="javascript:validateEnterKeyOnRowCountField(event,this.form,this);">    
  <label style="cursor:pointer;" onclick="javascript:getList(getFormObject(this),20,1000);">Per Page</label> 
</li>
<li>
  <label style="cursor:pointer;" onclick="javascript:getListWithoutCondition(getFormNameValue(this));">
   <i class="ico ico-large-zoom"></i>
   View All
  </label>  
</li>
```

```
enter code here
```